# I am getting error - Object required

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro code which based on the cell input moves to one of the two sheets (service or event). I am getting error as 'Object required'

Any help to resolve this will be appreciated.

```
Sub GoSheetNext()

        Dim abcd As Integer
        abcd = ActiveWorksheet.Cells(4, 2).Value
        If abcd > 10 Then
            Sheets("service").Select
            ElseIf abcd < 10 Then
           Sheets("event").Select

        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: What happens if abcd = 10?  Where is the error? Have you tried .activate?

Comment: abcd will never be 10.

Comment: after first line, it says 'object required'.

Comment: I have tried .activate, it shows the same error

Comment: @VishalSachdev : How about accepting answers that helped you? ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's simply that `ActiveWorksheet` doesn't exists, it is `ActiveSheet` :

As mentioned by @John Coleman, you should add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, it'll *only* **force you to declare all of your variables** before being able to launch the code. So it'll have detected your issue here, because it wouldn't have recognised the `ActiveWorksheet`! ;)

```
Sub GoSheetNext()
Dim Test_Value As Integer
Test_Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).Value

If Test_Value > 10 Then
    Sheets("service").Select
ElseIf Test_Value < 10 Then
    Sheets("event").Select
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Good answer. Maybe it couldn't hurt to mention that `Option Explicit` would give a `Variable Not Defined` error while highlighting `ActiveWorksheet ` -- which might be easier to debug